# Missing assemblies that aren't described anywhere

Tags: .net

I've just reinstalled the operating system and suddenly my legacy project from early 2013's won't compile.

The warnings I'm getting are:

> Found conflicts between different versions of
>   "System.Windows.Interactivity" that could not be resolved.  These
>   reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is
>   set to detailed.

-

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
>   disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.

-

> The type 'LocalReport' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral.

The last one won't let me ALT+ENTER the issue, the reference simply doesn't add.

I've tried googling all of these to get things I have to install, but surprisingly I found nothing, so I would appreciate any input.

Comment: For 1 and 2 -> On the Visual Studio you could try go to the properties of the referenced Assemblies and you can set CopyLocal to true .

Comment: @Arouri it was set like this by default, no avail.

Comment: It now compiles, but I still get first two of these errors.
To anyone having the 3rd error - Go to C:\Windows\assembly\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms and remove folder that doesn't match your version (ex: 11.0.0.0).

You can also try enforcing version in your project - but if you are like me and you can't change project at all (requirements from team leader) - then this is your solution.